# Parsing a simple language for title formatting

Tags: java

I'm writing an audio player using java, and I want a title formatter similar to foobar2000. Examples are:

```
$if($strcmp(%album artist%,%artist%),%artist%,$if2(%album%,Unknown))
```

or

```
[%album%][ '('CD $ifgreater(%totaldiscs%,1,%discnumber%,)')']
```

first example returns a string, and if it is same for sequential tracks in a playlist, they are grouped, second example formats album name and adds a cd number if it exists. Full reference is [here](http://wiki.hydrogenaudio.org/index.php?title=Foobar2000:Titleformat_Reference#Additional_Reading)

I do not need everything but at least some of the functionality.

How difficult is it to write a parser for such a language. Are there any compiler compilers for java?

Would it be easier to use java's javascript engine? How fast will it be (processing several thousand tracks)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some tools around for parsing custom languages. One of the common tools is the parser generator [antlr](http://www.antlr.org/).

To answer your question, if it's difficult? Yes, it is. Parsing the statements into a syntax tree is just the first step. You still need to write the  interpreter, and this foobar2000 title generator syntax looks pretty complex!

Comment: antlr looks like a solution. i guess my program will not have configurable title formatting. :) maybe later.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using a templating engine such as [Freemarker](http://freemarker.org/) or [Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/)? Their markup languages aren't exactly what you specified, but they're very flexible. Might be too verbose if it's for end-users, though.