# Any Java support for scripting language syntax similar to Foobar2000:Title Formatting Reference

Tags: java, javascript

Previously Id asked this question [Putting a simple expression language into java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6285045/putting-a-simple-expression-language-into-java) about allowing the user to enter a formatting mask with support for if statements, substrings and the like.

The answer to use Script Engine with javascript worked , however the javascript syntax is not very easy for users

```
(albumartist.length>0  ? albumartist +'-' :(artist.length>0 ? artist + '-' : ' ')) + (album.length>0 ? album + '-' :'') + (trackno.length>0 ? trackno + '-' :'')  + title
```

could give output

```
U2-Boy-Twilight-02
```

but an easier syntax would be something like

```
if(%albumartist%,%artist%)-if(%album%,%album%-)if(%trackno%,%trackno-)%title
```

The main difference being is we don't have to explicity concatenate strings with '+' or quote string literals with ' '

which is similar to the Foobar title formatting reference detailed at http://wiki.hydrogenaudio.org/index.php?title=Foobar2000:Title_Formatting_Reference#.24if2.28a.2Celse.29 but there is not a physical implemention of this I could parse in Java.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Just curious: How do you escape "if" and "%" literals?

Comment: I dont that would be a problem in my scenario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- AFAIK, only javascript (ECMAScript) is supported in the standard JDK. You can check what engines are available with the code below.
- Other engines are available in the [scripting project](http://java.net/projects/scripting/sources/svn/show/trunk/engines?rev=236), but I don't believe that the language you mention is part of them.
- If you feel like it (and have a lot of spare time), you can [create your own scripting engine](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/programmer_guide/index.html#engineimpl).

You can read more about engines [here](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2006/04/11/scripting-for-java-platform.html), [there](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2006/09/21/making-scripting-languages-jsr-223-aware.html) and [there](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-04-2006/jw-0424-scripting.html).

Finally you could "simply" [parse the FooBar2000 syntax in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188889/parsing-a-simple-language-for-title-formatting).

To summarise, **what you are trying to do does not sound like an easy task** - good luck! ;-)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
    List<ScriptEngineFactory> factories =
            mgr.getEngineFactories();
    for (ScriptEngineFactory factory : factories) {
        String engName = factory.getEngineName();
        String engVersion = factory.getEngineVersion();
        String langName = factory.getLanguageName();
        String langVersion = factory.getLanguageVersion();
        System.out.printf("Script Engine: %s (%s)\n", engName, engVersion);
        System.out.printf("\tLanguage: %s (%s)\n", langName, langVersion);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ha, the foobar link shows somebody had the same ideas and backed away from a solution

Comment: Looks like Im going to stick with Javascript, but provide some preconfigured masks

Comment: @PaulTaylor Sounds reasonable!